# Replace all occurrences of a string found in a file using values from another file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a CSV file (`data.csv`) as below:

```
apple_val, balloon_val, cherry_val, dog_val
1         ,5           ,6          ,7
3         ,19          ,2          ,3
```

I have a text file (`sentence.txt`) as below:

```
I have apple_val apple(s) and balloon_val balloons. My dog_val dogs were biting the cherry_val cherries.
```

I want my output file (`output.txt`) as below:

```
I have 1 apple(s) and 5 balloons. My 7 dogs were biting the 6 cherries.
I have 3 apple(s) and 19 balloons. My 3 dogs were biting the 2 cherries.
```

I used the below script. But my script is specific to the above example.

```
awk -F "," {print $1, $2, $3, $4} data.csv | while read a, b, c,d
do
    sed -e "s/apple_val/$a/g" -e "s/balloon_val/$b/g" -e "s/dog_val/$d/g" -e "s/cherry_val/$c/g" sentence.txt >> output.txt
done
```

I want to make it generic by reading the first line of the CSV file (the header) and replacing the occurrences of those strings (like apple_val) in the text file.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified [alienth](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230200/89144) variant (arrays is used):

```
#!/bin/bash
tr -s ',' ' ' <data.csv | {
read -a tokens
while read -a values; do
    for index in $(seq 0 $((${#tokens[*]}-1))); do
        echo "s/${tokens[$index]}/${values[$index]}/g"
    done | sed -f - sentence.txt
done
}
```

Same with `awk`:

```
awk -F"[, ]+" '
NR == FNR{
    s=s $0 "\n"
    next}
FNR == 1{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        val[i]=$i
    next}
{
    p=s
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        gsub(val[i], $i, p)
    printf p}
' sentence.txt data.csv
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The script using awk is replacing correctly, except it expects a comma at the end of each line. dog_val is getting replaced only if comma is added at the end.

Comment: @Aarthi the script is work as expected on your example data without any additional comma(s).

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do here is known as 'templating', and doing your own templating is often rife with unexpected potholes :)

Here is a shell script which will do what you're asking, but it ain't pretty and is probably quite fragile. I'd highly recommend looking at a more robust templating solution.

```
#!/bin/bash

sentence=$(cat sentence.txt)

tokens=$(head -n1 data.csv | cut -d, -f1- --output-delimiter="")

cat data.csv | tail -n +2 | while read i; do
    token_number=0
    new_sentence=$sentence
    for token in $tokens; do
        let token_number+=1
        value=$(echo $i | cut -d, -f${token_number})
        new_sentence=$(echo $new_sentence | sed -e "s/${token}/${value}/g")
    done
    echo $new_sentence
done
```

Result output, given the input you specified in the question:

```
I have 1 apple(s) and 5 balloons. My 7 dogs were biting the 6 cherries.
I have 3 apple(s) and 19 balloons. My 3 dogs were biting the 2 cherries.
```

Comment: If you use *tokens* and *values* as arrays it will be much easy to call it by array index.